# How can i pass a value to constructors of collection of instances at runtime with simple injector?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I know that I can pass a value to single instance:

```
container.Register(() => new Service(value));
```

But I want to register a collection of instances using collection of assemblies, like this:

```
container.RegisterCollection<IService>(assemblies);
```

All instances have equal constructor signature. How do I pass a value to all constructors?

**Update**

Due to Steven's comment i should clarify that a value i want to pass is `CancellationToken`.

Comment: Some crucial information is missing from the question (that was stated in a comment on one of the answers) and that's that the data that needs to be injected is a cancelation token. Such cancelation token is runtimr data and runtime data [should not be injected into components' constructors](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a good idea to depend on primitive values. A service should depend on abstractions. Create a new interface describing the service that supplies the necessary value and have the instances depend on that. If different instances need different values, they should depend on separate interfaces to supply the values. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24639348/1102300) gives more details and has an example of how to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Verdolino - agreed, and edited accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I've read that answer. But I don't have any duplicated code and there is nothing to extract to separate interface and concrete type. I just need to pass a CancellationToken to service instances to stop all threading and dataflow activity when it is necessary. Token has to be the same for all instances. How should I create a describing interface that supplies token? Token source has to be accessible in composition root.

Comment: The initial code looks like you're passing a value to a constructor. Are you trying to pass a CancellationToken to the constructor of all your service instances?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: Create an `ICancellationTokenProvider` and let your service depend on that. The implementation of that interface now gives you the flexibility to make choices later about how or whether to return a token, even if it doesn't need that level of logic now.

Comment: Or pass the cancelation token on through the public API of your services. That token seems runtime data to me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a simple foreach loop to accomplish this?  This code is not tested...

```
Collection<IService> myServices = new Collection<IService>();
myServices.Add(service1);
myServices.Add(service2);

foreach (IService svc in myServices) 
{
     container.Register(svc);
}
```